# Linux DHCP server option 43 vendor-encapsulated-options, how to format/encode?

Tags: linux, dhcp-server, dhcp-option

I admin the network for a small business which has an IPCop firewall box providing DHCP services to the network (and various other services). The DHCP server in IPCop appears to be dhcpd and IPCop provides a web-based front end to editing the configuration file.

I'm looking to use the vendor-encapsulated-options option to send particular values for DHCP options 66 and 67 to a particular vendor-class-identifier. The purpose being the auto-configuration of some VoIP phones which support DHCP options 66/67 and 43/60.

I've already managed to get options 66 tftp-server-name and 67 bootfile-name working to auto-configure the phones. But of course these options are global and sent to all DHCP clients. I'm looking to experiment with the vendor-class-indentifier and vendor-encapsulated-options DHCP options to send the auto-configure information only to the phones. I realise this is probably overkill for a small business network but this is all to broaden my knowledge.

So I started reading through some information that's out there and I just cannot work out how to encode options 66/67 within a vendor-encapsulated-options string.
Here's the relevant RFC... https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132#section-8 section 8.4
And here's the man page for dhcpd http://www.daemon-systems.org/man/dhcp-options.5.html under "VENDOR ENCAPSULATED OPTIONS"

Those documents seem to suggest that the options are to be encoded in HEX format, however looking at the man page example of the vendor-encapsulated-options option...

```
The value of this option can be set in one of two ways.  
The first way is to simply specify the data directly,  
using a text string or a colon-separated list of hexadecimal values.  
For example:  
       option vendor-encapsulated-options
           2:4:AC:11:41:1:
           3:12:73:75:6e:64:68:63:70:2d:73:65:72:76:65:72:31:37:2d:31:
           4:12:2f:65:78:70:6f:72:74:2f:72:6f:6f:74:2f:69:38:36:70:63;
```

When I try and decode that lot from HEX to ASCII I get the following:
`????A?????????sundhcp-server17-1????????/export/root/i86pc`
So I'm sure I'm not understanding the format/encoding properly.

Here's my snippet from IPCop's dhcpd.conf

```
subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 #GREEN
{
        range 192.168.1.30 192.168.1.200;
        option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
        option domain-name "domain.com";
        option routers 192.168.1.1;
        option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.1;
        option ntp-servers 192.168.1.1;
        option netbios-name-servers 192.168.1.3;
        default-lease-time 43200;
        max-lease-time 172800;
        option vendor-encapsulated-options "hello";
        option vendor-class-identifier "snom320";
        option vendor-class-identifier "snom821";
        option bootfile-name "voipsettings/firstboot.xml";
        option tftp-server-name "http://username:password@intranet.domain.com";
} #GREEN
```

I have the vendor-class-identifiers set per the value submitted by the VoIP phones (Snom) in the DHCP request. The bootfile-name and tftp-server-name are the options (66/67) that I'm looking to encode in the vendor-encapsulated-options.
Snom have a guide on their wiki here...
`http://wiki.snom.com/Networking/DHCP/Options#Auto_Provisioning_Options`
(Apologies, my reputation is too low to post >2 links in a question)
That wiki seems to suggest that I need to encode the vendor-class-identifier as a "string of n octets"
Furthermore, the examples of the vendor-encapsulated-options given on that wiki article also return gibberish when converting from HEX to ASCII. So there's something critical that I'm not understanding here.

Can anyone give me a run-down of how to format/encode these DHCP options properly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

DHCP Option 43 is a bit of an odd beast.  Vendors can treat it however they want - some expect the option numbers to match with the DHCP option numbers, others do not.

The basic structure is 1 byte for an option ID, 1 byte for the length of the option data (n), then n bytes of the actual option data - and, rinse and repeat.

---

Let's take the example from dhcp-options.  They've stuck the newlines in strategic places to make it easier to read. In reality, the setting they've configured is just this:

```
02:04:AC:11:41:01:03:12:73:75:6e:64:68:63:70:2d:73:65:72:76:65:72:31:37:2d:31:04:12:2f:65:78:70:6f:72:74:2f:72:6f:6f:74:2f:69:38:36:70:63;
```

Which is pretty hard to read unless you know what you're looking for.  Let's break down the parts:

- Byte 1, `0x02`.  This says that this block is config for option number 2.  How that's interpreted is up to the vendor.
- Byte 2, `0x04`.  This says that the data for option 2 will occupy the next 4 bytes.
- Bytes 3-6, `0xAC114101`.  These four bytes are the actual data.  As you saw when you tried to decode it, it's not readable data.
- Byte 7, the **start of the next option block**, `0x03`.  The whole chain starts over again, this says that the following config is for option 3.
- *and so on, for 3 sections*

Another example, from the snom wiki page:

```
42:0c:68:74:74:70:3a:2f:2f:74:65:73:74:00:43:12:73:6e:6f:6d:2f:73:65:74:74:69:6e:67:73:2e:70:68:70:00;
```

- Byte 1, `0x42`.  42 in hex is 66, for option code 66.
- Byte 2, `0x0c`.  Length of 12 bytes.
- Bytes 3-14, `0x687474703a2f2f7465737400`.  This is `http://test` with a null byte (`0x00`) on the end.  Not sure why they have that there.
- Byte 15, `0x43`.  Option 67.
- Byte 16, `0x12`.  18 byte length.
- Bytes 17-34, `0x736e6f6d2f73657474696e67732e70687000`.  `snom/settings.php`.  Again, the null byte at the end.

---

So, let's say you need to construct an option 43 with `http://phone.example.com` as an option 66 and `phonesettings.txt` as option 67.

- Byte 1, option code 66, `0x42`
- Byte 2, length of 24 bytes on `http://phone.example.com`, so `0x18`
- Bytes 3-26, the data.  `0x687474703a2f2f70686f6e652e6578616d706c652e636f6d`
- Byte 27, option code 67, `0x43`
- Byte 28, length of 17 bytes on `phonesettings.txt`, so `0x11`
- Bytes 29-45, data.  `0x70686f6e6573657474696e67732e747874`

So, a complete config string of :

```
42:18:68:74:74:70:3a:2f:2f:70:68:6f:6e:65:2e:65:78:61:6d:70:6c:65:2e:63:6f:6d:43:11:70:68:6f:6e:65:73:65:74:74:69:6e:67:73:2e:74:78:74;
```

If that doesn't work, try adding the null bytes to the end of the data strings (and increase the length field accordingly) as in their example - they may either desire null bytes at the end of each option or an even number of bytes for each option's length.  That's the downside of option 43 - they can do whatever they want!

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation! I think the reason I was confused was because I was trying to decode the whole thing as ascii to work out the format. But as you've pointed out, the first 2 bytes of each encoded option are decimal, not ascii. And it looks like this formatting is used in quite a few DHCP options. I've written a dirty function in PHP which I can use to build this format and also decode, I'll post as an answer.

Comment: The next step is to work out the dhcpd configuration syntax to combine the vendor-encapsulated-options with the vendor-class-identifier. But I don't think it's possible to do this using IPCop's DHCP admin interface. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

That's definitively the most crapy way to configure the option 43.
You should instead use the ISC's "vendor option space" syntax that allows you to get a human read of what you configured and avoid mistakes:

```
option space db;
option db.db-server code 1 = ip-address;
option db.loginid code 2 = text;
option db.db-name code 3 = text;
```

Jean-Yves Bisiaux

Answer (score 2):

Remember to use local-encapsulation:

```
option space cisco;
option cisco.wlc code 241 = array of ip-address;
option local-encapsulation code 43 = encapsulate cisco;
option cisco.wlc 10.7.3.6, 10.7.3.2;
```